# How to compute the scores based on field data in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following fields in documents

```
{
name: "Pearl",
age : 43,
weight: 54,
bodyWeight : 103,
height : 1.8
}
```

Now i want to get scores for the documents based on the bodyWeight to height ratio of the documents. How to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "bodyWeight to height ratio" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using scripting. Try the script below:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "functions": [
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": "_score * doc['bodyWeight'].value / doc['height'].value"
          }
        }
      ],
      "score_mode": "sum",
      "boost_mode": "replace"
    }
  }
}
```

Like wise you can compute score using field data. For more reference in scoring you can visit [here](http://blog.qbox.io/scoring-using-elasticsearch-scripts-part1)

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch provides custom scoring via the [function score query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html). In your case, you can score documents with a [custom script scoring](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#_script_score):

```
"script_score" : {
    "script" : "doc['bodyWeight'].value / doc['height'].value"
}
```

While this seems like a fast and easy solution, it has two problems:
* scoring will have an interesting behavior in case the value of `height` is 0: Infinity?
* script scoring is slow

A solution could be to index the weight in your document

```
{
  name: "Pearl",
  age : 43,
  weight: 54,
  bodyWeight : 103,
  height : 1.8
  ratio: 57.2
}
```

and subsequently [score by field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#_field_value_factor)

```
"field_value_factor": {
  "field": "ratio"
}
```